# Logarithmic scale with base 2

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following pairs of points that I want to plot using a logarithmic scale.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
xdata = [256, 512, 1024, 2048]
ydata = [1, 2, 30, 150]
ax.scatter(xdata, ydata)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
ax.set_xlim(xmin=0)
plt.show(f)
```

[image]

The points render but I don't know how to make the scale logarithmic to the base of 2 on both axes. I want every increment to double the value e.g. x increments should be 0, 256, 512, 1024, 2048 (bytes) and y increments should be minutes where the data now is in seconds: 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is called a *logarithmic* scale (rather than exponential). I guess this is why you failed to find the answer yourself, otherwise you could easily arrive at the [corresponding matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/log_demo.html).

The following should work (the only discrepancy from your requirements is that the axes labels are in the form of 2<sup>n</sup> rather than plain numbers):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
xdata = [256, 512, 1024, 2048]
ydata = [1, 2, 30, 150]
plt.xscale('log', basex=2)
plt.yscale('log', basey=2)
ax.scatter(xdata, ydata)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
plt.show(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for the new way to do it, since

```
plt.xscale('log', basex=2)
```

is not working anymore, use

```
ax.set_xscale('log', base=2)
```